# Ugly request payload occurred while uploading documents using BLOB through FormData

Tags: javascript, blob, multipartform-data, form-data, amazon-waf

I'm appending a BLOB in the FormData like,

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('xyz', blob);
```

While uploading this blob, following is the ugly payload I've seen(this ugly data is too long to show here).

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xyz"; filename="xyz.png"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG


IHDRà5ÑÜä IDATx^\½i\i¥g¾/A23««» ÂHh©×ZÔ=ÐHúÿ¿@ôQ½Õ$cñÝ¯ð<ÇÞ %öp²2Ép¿÷]l9vìØì¿ÿoÿvº\¯õ°¨ût¯óý\÷ºÖz»ªé~©UÝk5j9¿×v³ªÏ_¾Ôùr­Ù|UëÕ¶f³y]n×ºM×ªùTóÅTÓt«ÛíRó¥¶«}}Ø.....

------WebKitFormBoundary1wDstGejHPb3PhBI
```

Due to which server is blocking this file to be get uploaded with [HTTP 403 Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) error. As there are some rules applied at the server side using [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_IN&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=waf_b&sc_content=web_application_firewall_e&sc_detail=amazon%20waf&sc_category=waf&sc_segment=159812276057&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=IN&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!159812276057!e!!g!!amazon%20waf&ef_id=WvmHJgAAAi1HzMFc:20180614085105:s). These rules are re:SQL injection, XSS, etc.

I think, those rules are blocking the request because of this ugly payload and if I append basic file object(not a BLOB), 403 error is not coming! **It works properly with the File Object and this error comes only for BLOB upload**.

Let me know your thoughts and how to prevent it!

Comment: Encode the BLOB with base64 on client sid and decode it on the server side, and you’re good to go.

Comment: Do you set content-type header as multipart/form-data?

Comment: What is "ugly" in this request exactly? All I see is a normal FormData request with a file sent as binary, just like it should be.